# PDO with OFFSET and Limit fetching all records

Tags: php

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id!=1 ORDER BY first_name LIMIT ?,? ";    

            $data=array();
            $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql) or die("failed!");
            $statement->bindParam(1, $position,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement->bindParam(2, $limit,PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $statement->execute();

            while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                  $data[] = $row;
            }
```

The query run but its fetching all records and also where and order by not working. can anybody help me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the query like this:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where id !=:id LIMIT :limit, :offset");
$stmt->execute(['id'=>$id,'limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset]); 
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply, I did try but the result is same  and showing all records.

Comment: could you please share the table and data you want to fetch?

Comment: Thanx for the reply I have sort it Actually where I was running this query along with this I am also again second query which is getting all records so I didn't notice before and spend couple of hours to fix it. finally I laughed on me and then figure out. Thanx to all for helping me in this matter. The problem is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = 1;
$offset = 0;
$limit = 5;

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where id !=:id ORDER BY first_name LIMIT :offset, :limit");
$stmt->execute([':id'=>$id,':limit' => $limit, ':offset' => $offset]); 
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($data);
exit;
```

Comment: Thanx again, I run this query but I am so confused its same result. The result is array(4)  where you can notice that array shows 4 and I have a total records 4 in my table

Comment: array(4) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(39) ["first_name"]=> string(5) "david" ["last_name"]=> string(6) "david2" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(40) ["first_name"]=> string(7) "catania" ["last_name"]=> string(5) "helen" } [2]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(45) ["first_name"]=> string(4) "loca" ["last_name"]=> string(4) "loca" } [3]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(46) ["first_name"]=> string(6) "marina" ["last_name"]=> string(9) "marina jo" } }

Comment: @inocent -  `$limit = 5;` in my example means maximum 5 records, so if you have only 4 records, it will obviously show all of 4. change `$limit = 5;` to `$limit = 2;` and try

Comment: yes I changed it to 2 and also change to 1 but the result is again same in every case

Comment: Strange, may be you are looking result from some another query, not this one? ..

Comment: this is also very strange to me every thing is perfect and I am using fetching the data with the same query